# Simple reactive list binding fails in 6.5.0 version of ReactiveUI on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I've got a weird error when trying to create a simple sample using the latest version of Reactive UI.

The window opens and I get a system error

> Couldn't find view for 'Hi Bob!'

note: 'Hi Bob!' is the first item in the list.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

versions
ReactiveUI 6.5.0
Splat 1.6.2
.net 4.5

Sample code

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ListBind.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListBox Name="ListBox1"></ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace ListBind
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, IViewFor<ViewModel>
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            ViewModel = new ViewModel();
            DataContext = ViewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, m => m.Items, v => v.ListBox1.ItemsSource);
        }
        public ViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return (ViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(ViewModel), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        object IViewFor.ViewModel
        {
            get { return ViewModel; }
            set { ViewModel = (ViewModel)value; }
        }
    }
    public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public ReactiveList<string> Items = new ReactiveList<string>(new[] { "Hi Bob!", "Two", "Three" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing with `ReactiveUI` when you bind to things like a `ListBox` using the `OneWayBind` method, is that it will try to automatically apply a custom template for the data based upon the views it finds with `Splat.Locator.Resolve`. In your case, it is trying to find and build a view based on the "Hi Bob!" ViewModel, which obviously doesn't exist.

What you should do is force it to use a custom data template so that it doesn't try to apply a non-existing template. With a template below, it shouldn't try and resolve a view for you, but rather stick the "Hi Bob!" value into the `TextBlock`.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

There is a slim chance that ReactiveUI will still ignore that (I cannot verify right now), so if that is the case, replace the `OneWayBind` binding with the traditional `ItemSource={Binding Data}`.

Comment: I'm just learning the basics of ReactiveUI so my opinion is, of course, quite biased. That being said - this seems like a massive overkill for such a basic application. Would this not be better to be better handled by Reactive UI?

Creating a basic binding for a listView went from 3 characters to many lines of ... unnecessary xaml + code behind